# Fast library for approximate nearest neighbors (FLANN) use in Matlab

Tags: matlab, flann

I'd like to use Fast library for approximate nearest neighbors (FLANN) in Matlab 2010, Windows 7. However, the error message below occurs.

```
Undefined function or method 'nearest_neighbors' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
```

nearest_neighbors file is cpp file. I think there should be some kind of build process, but I'm not familiar with build process.

Can anybody give me some guide about this problem?
I hope I can get some solutions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It builds with [CMake](http://www.cmake.org). You need to install CMake and also some C++ compiler, for example Microsoft Visual Studio. If you use 64-bit Matlab, the compiler should be capable to create 64-bit code.

You should also configure Matlab's mex tool by running `mex -setup` in Matlab.

After installing CMAKE and configuring compiler in Matlab, do the following.

1. Run cmake-gui
2. Enter path to FLANN sources on your hard drive in the "Source" entry field, for example `c:\flann`
3. Go to the next entry line of CMake GUI and enter some path on your hard drive, where you want compiled FLANN binaries to appear, for example, `c:\flann\build`. CMake will create this directory if it doesn't exist
4. Press "Configure" button and select a compiler.
5. CMake inspects your system and creates variables, storing settings. It shows them in the upper half of its window. New or changed variables are highlighted with red. Lower half of the window contains log messages.
6. Inspect variables and log and fix errors if any.
7. Repeat 4-6 if needed.
8. Press "Generate"

Now CMake has created a project for you. Kind of project depends on what compiler you have specified in 4. Now you should build this project.

You can also have CMake to run build process:
Open command prompt and enter the following

```
cd c:\flann\build
"c:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake" --build .
```

Correct paths according to your system.

After these steps completed, you should `add_path` in Matlab to the created library and be able to use it.